# Cloudinaryの導入について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

別のサイトでも質問をしているのですが、なかなか回答が付かないので、こちらでも質問させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/pe2pftxrptus3v

#### 実現したいこと

Ruby on Railsで作成したアプリをrender.comでアップしているのですが、
アプリの機能上、画像の保存も必要な為、Cloudinaryを使用するために、
CloudinaryにサインアップしてRubyのアプリに設定したのですが、
うまく保存できませんでした。

参考サイト
https://qiita.com/ttexan/items/a1004121e806c477d030

#### 前提

投稿エラーが起きた際の直近のエラーログを下記に記入しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Feb 22 04:33:44 PM  I, [2023-02-22T07:33:44.331773 #92]  INFO -- : [a836fee3-9779-45ab-9f69-30c74c9fb91b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1497ms (ActiveRecord: 224.0ms | Allocations: 87375)
Feb 22 04:33:44 PM  F, [2023-02-22T07:33:44.333028 #92] FATAL -- : [a836fee3-9779-45ab-9f69-30c74c9fb91b]
Feb 22 04:33:44 PM  [a836fee3-9779-45ab-9f69-30c74c9fb91b] CloudinaryException (Must supply api_key):
Feb 22 04:33:44 PM  [a836fee3-9779-45ab-9f69-30c74c9fb91b]
Feb 22 04:33:44 PM  [a836fee3-9779-45ab-9f69-30c74c9fb91b] app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

#### 該当のソースコード

config/cloudinary.yml

```
cloudinary:
  cloud_name: ********
  api_key: ********
  api_secret: ********
  
---
development:
  cloud_name: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] %>
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] %>
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
test:
  cloud_name: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] %>
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
```

Comment: 記事だと、`api_key`等の秘密情報は「`credential.yml`』に記述するように読み取りましたが、質問にある「該当のソースファイル」はそれに当たるのでしょうか? 明記した方がよいと思います。

Comment: credential.ymlにキー等を追記してデプロイして失敗しました。

Comment: credential.ymlの操作の部分がうまくいきません。EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:editをコマンドで打ってからcredential.ymlにキー等を追記したのですが、デプロイ失敗と表示されました。

Comment: それぞれの内容がどういうパスのファイルの内容なのか明記するようにしてみてください。この質問を見た人が質問者さんの問題を再現しやすくなるような書き方になっていると、回答を書きやすいです。

Comment: 少し質問を修正してどのファイルかを明記したのですが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: config/credentials.yml.enc を使っているなら暗号化されているので、復号のためのキーをRAILS_MASTER_KEY環境変数で与える必要があると思いますが、renderのWEB SERVICEのEnvironmentで環境変数を設定できていますか？
内容は config/master.key に記載されているものです。ローカルではこのファイルがありますが、renderに展開しているコードには含まれないと思うので。

Comment: RAILS_MASTER_KEYの環境設定はできています。

Comment: 参考サイトのEDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:editのコマンドの箇所がいまいちわからないのですが、credentials.ymlにCloudinaryのキーなどを記入して、そのあとに上記のコマンドを打つことで、正式の編集が完了されるのでしょうか？いまいち解釈ができていなくて申し訳ありません。

Comment: render shell で bundle exec rails runner "pp Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key]" と bundle exec rails runner "pp Cloudinary.config.api_key" として結果をみてCredentialやAPIキーが正しく設定されているか確認してください

Comment: 元記事を見てみたのですが、 config/cloudinary.yml にCredentialsの値を設定しているところ、 Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] ではなく <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] %> のようにERBで書かないとだめなのでは？と疑っています

Comment: cloud_name: ********などはCloudinary.ymlに記入しておいても大丈夫でしょうか？それともconfig/credentials.yml.encに書いたほうがいいのでしょうか？

Comment: cloudinary.ymlに書いてバージョン管理に含めてしまうと誰でも読める形で残ってしまうのでダメです。なのでcredentialsを使って暗号化し、別に保管したRAILS_API_KEYが無いと読めないようにするんです

Comment: それはrenderの環境設定でCloudinaryのキーをRAILS_API_KEYというように設定してconfig/credentials.yml.encに記入して保存してデプロイするということですか？それともコマンドなどで操作してconfig/credentials.yml.encを編集・保存する必要がありますか？

Comment: 違います。まずcredentialsを理解できていますか？上のコメントでrender shellで確認してみてくださいとお願いした確認されていますか？1つめのコマンドは、credentialsとmaster keyが正しく設定されているか。2つめのコマンドはcredentialsに保存したAPIキーを正しくCloudinary SDKに設定できているか確認するためのものです。それを確認しないと、どこで躓いているのかわかりません。

Comment: すみません。render shellで確認しようとしたのですが、無料の方は使えないようなのですが、shellは有料の方だけでしょうか？

Comment: あー https://render.com/docs/free に無料だとweb shellは使えないってありますね…。sshもダメみたいですね。残念。

Comment: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/ddde239ef12f8eb983666aa19511c10239af58d3/lib/cloudinary.rb#L149 のコードを読む限り、cloudinary.yml は ERB が使えるようですが、上のコメントで書いたように、このファイルの書き方に問題があるのでは？この書き方だと、APIキーとして "Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key]" という文字列が設定されている気がします。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143134/discussion-between-yuichi-takeuchi-and-sky)しましょう。

Comment: すみません。
とりあえず、<%= %>で囲って一度デプロイを試しています。
他のサイトを見たりしていると.envファイルを作成してCloudinaryを導入している方も見つけたのですが、それはまた別でしょうか?

Comment: やりかたはいろいろあるということです

Answer (score 0):

下記のサイトを参考にconfig/credentials.yml.encを編集したところ登録できました。
https://qiita.com/NaokiIshimura/items/2a179f2ab910992c4d39