# Cloudinaryかデータベースかどちらの設定が間違っているかわかりません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database

下記の質問を行い、設定できたのですが、
本番環境で画像の投稿を行おうとしたところエラーが起きました。

参考にしていたCloudinaryの設定は間違いなくできているはずなのですが、エラーが起きました。
renderのデータベースも作成し、renderで環境変数を設定したのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
こういう時にどちらを注視したほうがいいのでしょうか？
投稿時のエラーログを載せたgitも添付させていただきます。
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/2J445/dbf44b94834975fa4c0b13ea032c3796/raw/a376d2ded17a728c79d5954c7963b821a164e519/gistfile1.txt

DATABASE_URLはrenderで作成したデータベースの内部データベース URLを代入してきているのですが、合っていますでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記にデータベースの設定のコードを載せさせていただきます。
*****の所が自分が設定したデータベース関連のところなのですが、fromDatabase:のname:の箇所もdatabases:のname:の箇所と同一にしないといけないでしょうか？

```
databases:
  - name: *********
    databaseName: *********
    user: *********
    region: singapore


services:
  - type: web
    name: *********
    env: ruby
    region: singapore
    buildCommand: "./bin/render-build.sh"
    startCommand: "bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
    envVars:
      - key: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
        fromDatabase:
          name: render_app
          property: connectionString
      - key: <%= ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'] %>
        sync: false
```

[Cloudinaryの導入について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93957/cloudinary%e3%81%ae%e5%b0%8e%e5%85%a5%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6?noredirect=1#comment107323_93957)

Answer (score 1):

貼ってくれてるのはrender.yaml だと思いますが、このファイルはRailsが解釈するものではなく、ERB（<%=%>）を埋め込むことはできませんし、これではうまくいきません。

https://render.com/docs/deploy-rails#use-renderyaml-to-deploy
ドキュメント記載のものから書き換えているようですが…

> *****の所が自分が設定したデータベース関連のところなのですが、fromDatabase:のname:の箇所もdatabases:のname:の箇所と同一にしないといけないでしょうか？

そうですね！

> DATABASE_URLはrenderで作成したデータベースの内部データベース URLを代入してきているのですが、合っていますでしょうか？

間違っています。
下記のようになると思います。設定の意味は

- 環境変数 DATABASE_URL に
- 指定した名前のデータベースサービスの
- connectionStringプロパティの値をセットする（[プロパティ一覧）

です。

```
    envVars:
      - key: DATABASE_URL
        fromDatabase:
          name: databases の name: で設定している名前
          property: connectionString
```

また、RAILS_MASTER_KEYも <%=%> は要りません。

```
      - key: RAILS_MASTER_KEY
        sync: false
```

おそらく、先のcloudinaryの設定のYAMLでなぜだめだったのか、変更によってなぜうごいたのかをきちんと理解できていないため、ごっちゃになってるのだと思います。

Comment: DATABASE_URLに代入するのは内部データベース URLではなくて、パスワードの方ですか？

Comment: renderのデーターベースのconnectionStringプロパティはどこにありますか？

Comment: connectionStringは Internal Database URL に当たります。 https://render.com/docs/databases#connecting-from-apps-on-render 

ですが、このような値をrender.ymlに直接書くのはダメなので、render側で取得してきてDATABASE_URL環境変数に設定するための指定が、上記のものです。nameを設定すれば他を変更する必要ありません。

Comment: なお、fromDatabase などで指定できるプロパティ一覧は以下
https://render.com/docs/blueprint-spec#environment-variables

Comment: 会員登録機能（サインアップ機能）を試したところ会員登録されたのでデータベースは問題ないのかなと思いました。また、ユーザーのプロフィール画像だけ更新できなかったのでやはりCloudinaryがうまく導入されていなかったかもしれません。

Comment: credentials.yml.encの設定が問題だったかもしれません。ですが書き方で新しい問題が出てきたので別で質問を立てたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。
Cloudinaryのgemを更新し、下記の質問のcredentials.yml.encの設定：2の書き方で設定できました。

[credentials.yml.encの設定によりrails consoleがエラーが起こる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/94039/credentials-yml-enc%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ab%e3%82%88%e3%82%8arails-console%e3%81%8c%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%93%e3%82%8b/94040#94040)