# credentials.yml.encの設定によりrails consoleがエラーが起こる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

こちらの質問で、Cloudinaryか、databaseが問題を探っていたところ、credentials.yml.encの設定が問題で、新しい問題が出てきました。
今の設定では

credentials.yml.encの設定：1

```
# cloudinary:
cloud_name: *******
api_key: **********
api_secret: **************
```

にしているのですが、そうするとCloudinary.ymlの
<%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:cloud_name] %>
に代入できません。
そこで

credentials.yml.encの設定：2

```
cloudinary:
　　cloud_name: *******
    api_key: **********
    api_secret: **************
```

に設定してrails consoleで設定されているか確認しようとしたのですが、
下記のエラーが発生して確認できません。

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/cloudinary-1.0.85/lib/cloudinary/helper.rb:254:in `block in included': undefined method `alias_method_chain' for ActionView::Base:Class
Did you mean?  alias_method (NoMethodError)
```

このエラーを調べているのですが、なかなか原因を特定できません。
credentials.yml.encの設定：2の書き方がいけないのでしょうか？
それとも他のファイルの記述が邪魔しているのでしょうか？

Comment: api_keyとsecret、編集履歴に残ってしまって誰でも見られる状態になっているので、ここに書き込んだものは無効化して新しく作り直すことをおすすめします。
https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520942-How-do-I-create-a-new-API-key-and-API-secret-or-remove-an-old-key-

Comment: モデレーターの方で編集履歴の[修正](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3004/19110)を行っています。少々お待ちください。それはそれとしてインターネットに一度漏れてしまったものは修正されて見れなくなっても漏れてしまったことには変わりないので、既にコメントされているように認証情報の無効化をお勧めします。

Comment: 修正が完了し、編集履歴から削除されました。

Comment: すみません。認証情報の無効化はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> このエラーを調べているのですが、なかなか原因を特定できません。

alias_method_chain でググればわかるのですが、alias_method_chain は昔あったメソッドで Rails 5の頃に非推奨になり、削除されました
https://railsguides.jp/5_0_release_notes.html#%E9%9D%9E%E6%8E%A8%E5%A5%A8
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46705

cloudinary gemのバージョンが 1.0.85 のようですが、古すぎるためかと思います。最新を使いましょう。

> credentials.yml.encの設定：2の書き方がいけないのでしょうか？

逆で、書き方が正しくなったために、cloudinary gem が動作するようになり、エラーが表面化したのでしょう

Comment: 解決しました。
Cloudinaryのgemのバージョンを更新したところ、credentials.yml.encの設定が出来ました。
ありがとうございます。